# Filtrar items de FormArray

Tags: angular, filtro

Tengo un `FormArray` que se compone de `FormGroup` con la siguiente estructura:

```
let formGroup: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    checked: this.fb.control(false),
    id_lista: this.fb.control(element.id_lista[0]),
    nombre: this.fb.control(element.nombre),
    codigoInterno: this.fb.control(element.codigo_interno),
    porcentaje_original: this.fb.control({ value: element.porcentaje_revision, disabled: true }),
    porcentaje: this.fb.control(element.porcentaje_revision, [Validators.min(10), Validators.max(100)]),
    auditoria_original: this.fb.control({ value: element.porcentaje_auditoria, disabled: true }),
    auditoria: this.fb.control(element.porcentaje_auditoria, [Validators.min(10), Validators.max(100)]),
});
```

Y los muestro en el *HTML* asi:

```
<tr *ngFor="let saleList of salesListArray.controls [formGroupName]="index">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="checked" (change)="onChange(saleList, $event.target.checked)">
    </td>
 ....
</tr>
```

Intente hacer un `Filter`:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'filter' })
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    public transform(values: any[], filter: string): any[] {
        if (!values || !values.length) return [];
        if (!filter) return values;

        return values.filter(v => v.value.nombre.indexOf(filter) >= 0);
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, me devuelve los items filtrados pero sin valores, solo los `FormGroup`.

**ACTUALIZACION**

Estimados, encontre el error, al parecer al no tener un index dentro del `ngFor` se perdian los datos y por eso no cargaban.

```
<tr *ngFor="let saleList of salesListArray.controls | filter: searchText; let i=index;" [formGroupName]="i">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como deje en mi respuesta, al parecer era que no había un Index dentro del `ngFor` por lo que si filtraba los valores de manera correcta, pero no los cargaba correctamente en el DOM, espero que a alguien más le sirva.

```
<tr *ngFor="let saleList of salesListArray.controls | filter: searchText; let i=index;" [formGroupName]="i">
```